# Link button is not being disabled, how to disable link button in grid-view?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview with a link button in the first column. Once the link button is clicked I want to open a window, but I also want to disable the link button.

**Not working**
Once I click on the link button the window behavior is the expected one. However, the link button is not disabled. Therefore is permitting me to click on it over and over again.

**The front end is:**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkbtnView" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id")%>' OnCommand="GetViewOnClientClick" >View<br/></asp:LinkButton>
```

**GetviewonClientClick method:**

```
protected void GetViewOnClientClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
    if (row != null)
    {
        int index = row.RowIndex;

        LinkButton link = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("lnkbtnView");
        link.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

**Why is not working as expected?**
That's what I want to solve.  I suspect I might have to do a rebinding or something related, but I don't quite understand what is really going on. Therefore, I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: You could also simply do `lb.Enabled = false;`, however in both cases it works when I tested it. Or the popup window is preventing the PostBack in which case `GetViewOnClientClick` is never fired. But I cannot test that with the above snippet.

Comment: link.Enabled = false; in the original post has the same functionality as the suggested fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never found the solution to edit the control in that method. What I did instead was to read on the cycles of the grid view events.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events(v=vs.110).aspx

If you read the previous link, you'll know that once you click on a record it is going to trigger a call to the RowDataBound event. Therefore; in the RowDataBound event you'll have access to the control and apply logic to edit the control's properties (such as color, disabled, enabled...).

Therefore, because I have two types of records in this grid view, I needed to store and to make persistent what records were clicked.

This is my fix to keep track of the clicked rows:

```
    protected void gvList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            gvs.SetHeaderArrows(e);
        }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int Id = (int)(e.Row.RowIndex);
            int? inspID = convert.ToIntQ(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "InspectionID"));
            string rowclicked = string.Format("clickedrow{0}", Id);

            if (convert.ToIntQ(Session[rowclicked]) != null)
            {

                if (Id == Convert.ToInt32(Session[rowclicked]))
                {
                    LinkButton button = (LinkButton) e.Row.FindControl("lnkbtnView");
                    button.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                    button.Enabled = false;

                }

                else
                {
                    LinkButton button = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkbtnView");
                    button.ForeColor = Color.DarkBlue;
                    button.Enabled = true;

                }

            }
```